# Export Eclipse plugIn

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wrote my first eclipse  plugin and I can export it by Export->deplyable plugin and fragments.
I'm looking for a way to export it as .jar file by command line or Ant file
(i want to add it to build proccess of some componenets)

i will appricate ant help with that!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you will need to look into "Headless PDE Builds."

Take a look at the Eclipse PDE (Plug-in Development Environment), specifically the headless build (a.k.a., building without going through the IDE): http://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-build/.  Also, there is http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/Build.

Lars Vogel has some really good material on this subject from which I also learned (Thanks Lars!): http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePDEBuild/article.html.  As an additional note, his Eclipse RCP, Plugin, and OSGi development page has some really good articles as well: http://www.vogella.de/eclipse.html.

Also, if you would like to export for multiple platforms, be sure to download the delta pack for the version of Eclipse you are using (e.g., if using Eclipse 3.6.2, download the Eclipse Delta Pack version 3.6.2).

If you need to access any SVN repositories from within your scripts (e.g., Ant), use the SVN pde-build plugin at http://svn-pde-build.sourceforge.net/.

Lastly, run a web search containing items like "PDE headless build".  There are several links to sites that cover PDE building, customizing, and execution.

Sorry for not having a detailed list of instructions but the above links should help get you on the right path.

Comment: These links helped me- thanks, but now when I'm using the build.xml that created for me i getting many compile errors, that i'm not getting when i export the plugon manually using eclipse, thanks!!